# Can I run nest a $('element.class').each() function within the change() function for the same $('element.class')?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtml

Specifically, I want to iterate over every  element on the page, each time the value of one changes.

So to paraphrase my code I have:

```
$('select.filterbox').change(function() {
  // stuff
  $('select.filterbox').each(function() {
    // other stuff
  });
});
```

'stuff' all executes just fine, but 'other stuff' doesn't happen

Here's the full code

```
        // On Filterbox Change
    $j('select.filterbox').change(function() {

        // Show All Rows
        $j('#table1 tr').show();

        // For Each Filterbox
        $j('select.filterbox').each(function() {

            var selVal = $j(this).attr('value');
            var col = $j(this).closest('th').parent().children().index($j(this).closest('th'));
            alert('Column '+val+' : '+selVal);

            // If Selected Value Not Empty
            if(selVal != "") {

                // For Each Row
                $j('#table1 tr').each(function() {
                    var $tds = $j(this).find('td');
                    var cellVal = $tds.eq(col).text();
                    cellVal = $j.trim(cellVal);

                    // If td text != selected
                    if( cellVal != selVal ) {

                        // Hide this row
                        $j(this).hide();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you have posted, both `stuff` and `other stuff` should run.

Comment: Make a jsFiddle? The way 'other stuff' is coded could be wrong.

Comment: What is it that you think might not work?  In other words, what do you suspect *might* make it not work?

Comment: Post your real js.. Probably problem somewhere around.

Comment: Are you afraid that changing the elements will trigger another change event? Thus throwing you into an infinite loop?

Comment: Have you tried to invoke your variables outside the `each` functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: yes you can.  I've done a lot of stuff like that recently.  Indeed, your code should do it.  It is likely that you've made some small but significant error in your code that will need to be hunted down and fixed.  I've done a lot of stuff stuff like *that* recently, too.

More helpful answer: do things to figure out where the breakdown is.  replace the "$('select.filterbox').each()" call with something obvious - say, calling .hide() on large chunks of your page.  Make sure that line of code is even being called.  If it is being called, put the "$('select.filterbox').each()" call back, then move the hide() call inside of it.  If that works, then you know that it's running at least once.  Change the hide() call to a (this).hide(), and see if you can see which one it's identified.  Once you've narrowed down where it's failing you, it'll be a lot easier to figure out what you've done wrong.

Comment: Thank you!  was referring to "val", a variable i hadnt defined *facepalm*  Thanks to all for looking

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but it's not optimal to attach separate event handlers to a lot of elements. You can take advantage of event bubbling and just attach a single handler to their parent container. For example:

```
$("#filters").change(function (evt) {
    // evt.target will give you actual element that changed
    $("#filters select.filterbox").each(function () {
        // other stuff
    });
});
```

Comment: So for this to work I would have to give each select an id="filters"?

Comment: No, that's for the container for all your `<select>` elements. You don't have to use an id. It just need to be something specific enough to cover all its `<select>` children and nothing more.